# Is it possible to git color based on file type?

Tags: git, command-line

Is it possible to configure git to have have different colors depending of file? So for example:

```
>git COMMAND-WITH-COLOR
```

would produce something like:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need `git` for this? If you have a modern version of `ls`, you can simply do a `ls --color` to get colours for all files depending  on type.

Comment: Well yes, but say for example I would like to find what commit a certain type of file was changed. Or if I look at a change I can very easy see if that change affected a certain file type. ls --color will only list current files in directory ....

Comment: Get the file list using any of the git commands that you want and then provide them as input to `ls` using `xargs` or substitution.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Ok, not as smooth as I hoped for but it will work. Thanks. If you like you can provide this as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the file list using any of the git commands that you want and then provide them as input to ls using xargs or substitution.